# How to fix this Syntax error in query expression?

Tags: database, ms-access, sdlc

I am working on Standard Access. I wrote this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE price < 40 AND
type IN ('Double", "Single")
ORDER BY price;
```

when I run it, it's telling me this message

> Syntax error in string in query expression price < 40 AND type IN
> ('Double", "Single") ORDER BY price;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes, not double quotes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM room WHERE price < 40 AND type IN ('Double', 'Single') ORDER BY price
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix single- and double-quotes. Also, `type` is a reserved word.
So try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE price < 40 AND [type] IN ("Double", "Single")
ORDER BY price;
```